# Equations in r package documentation do not work

Tags: r, package, roxygen2

I'm using roxygen2 for my package description and I want to have mathematic equations in my documentation. For example I want to write n_{u} like a formula. When I write \eqn{n_{u}} in @details nothing happens but the text is italic. I document the package with control, shift and d and then i push "Clean and rebuild".
Did I forget anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is expected behaviour. The R documentation format doesn't have "real" equations like you might get from Mathjax or another fully-fledged Latex engine; it uses a basic representation that just copies your equation text but sets it in italics. Think of it as more akin to code, rather than mathematical notation.

Comment: Damn, I forgot that this is expected. Shame on me.

Answer (score 3):

`\eqn{n_u}` is for the PDF documentation.

Write that instead:

```
\ifelse{html}{\out{n<sub>u</sub>}{\eqn{n_u}}
```

The syntax is:

```
\ifelse{html}{\out{HTML CODE}}{\eqn{LATEX-LIKE CODE}{ASCII}}
```

with `{ASCII}` optional is for the text documentation. `HTML CODE` is for the HTML documentation, and `LATEX-LIKE CODE` is for the PDF documentation.